# Angular Asynchronous function on controller not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have this function to set if some fields in the view are enabled. When the flow goes through the "else" clause I'm getting an error. I guess is related with having the "return" sentence inside the "then" scope. How can I modify the code to return the value correctly?

**Code**

```
vm.canBeEdited = function() {
  if (vm.viewing || !vm.myBalance || !vm.config || !vm.config.drawerBalanceAllowed) return false;
  if (vm.myBalance.balancingMethod === 'register')
    return vm.myBalance.ownerId && (vm.myBalance.status === 'none' || vm.myBalance.status === 'rejected');
  else {
    cashManagementService.getCashierId(loggedUser.username).then(function(userId) {
      return vm.myBalance.ownerId &&
            (vm.myBalance.status === 'none' || vm.myBalance.status === 'rejected') &&
            ((userId !== undefined && vm.myBalance.ownerId === userId) || securityService.hasRole('app://cash-management/drawer-balances/create'));
    });
  }
};
```

**Error**

```
Unhandled exception at line 146, column 132 in http://localhost:54203/Scripts/angular.min.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
```

This is the error referenced running in  Chrome but I don't understand how to apply it to my code:

```
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
```

Function getCashierId(name)

```
function getCashierId(name) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        getCatalogs().then(function(catalogs) {
            var cashiers = catalogs.cashiers;
            angular.forEach(cashiers, function(cashier) {
                if (cashier.name == name)
                    deferred.resolve(cashier.id);
            })
        }, function() {
            deferred.reject();
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    } 
function getCatalogs() {
        if (!catalogsResolver)
            catalogsResolver = $http.get(configuration.baseApiUrl + 'catalogs').then(function (response) {
                var catalogs = {
                    cashiers: response.data.cashiers,
                    configuration: response.data.configuration,
                    currencies: response.data.currencies,
                    baseCurrency: response.data.baseCurrency,
                    registers: response.data.registers,
                    tenders: response.data.tenders,
                    safeTenders: response.data.safeTenders
                };
                catalogs.configuration.activeDate = new Date(catalogs.configuration.activeDate);
                return catalogs;
            }, function (data) {
                catalogsResolver = null;
            });
        return catalogsResolver;
    }
```

**Controller Usage example**

```
vm.calculatorVisible = !vm.config.tenderManualEntry && vm.canBeEdited()
```

**View Usage example**

```
<label class="radio-inline" ng-class="{'text-muted' : vm.disableCashierRadioButton}">
    <input type="radio"
           ng-model="vm.myBalance.balancingMethod"
           ng-change="vm.balancingMethodChange()"
           value="cashier"
           ng-disabled="!vm.canBeEdited() || vm.disableCashierRadioButton" />
    {{ 'cashManagement.labels.cashier' | translate }}
</label>
```

Comment: According to the documentation the root cause of this error is duplication in functionality. It would be helpful if you could post the controller/factory that houses the function that you have posted. It would also be helpful if you could post how you are using that function in your HTML.

Comment: I would advise swapping the angular.min.js file with the full version of angular and refreshing. It will give you a much more specific error message than the min version. The error message you currently have is extremely vague, it is difficult to determine what the problem is.

Comment: The digest cycle is stuck in the infinite loop (that's what is said in the [error link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D)), apparently the code in that `else` branch somehow changes the scope's state and triggers digest, which hits `canBeEdited` again and it starts over again. Can you show what's inside `cashManagementService.getCashierId()` method?

Comment: The `ng-disabled` directive only works with functions that are synchronous and [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). In general functions should be avoided because they will be executed multiple times during a digest cycle. Refactor the code to compute the `ng-disabled` value in the `ng-change` directive. Or use an asychronous validator with the ngModelController.